# Show that the series is convergent/divergent. Which test should I use?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How do I test the convergence of the following series? I have no idea what test could be used to show that this series is convergent/divergent.
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{\sqrt[3]{n}}{n\left(\sqrt{n^2 + n\sqrt{n}} - n \right)}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remark that
$$\frac{\sqrt[3]{n}}{n(\sqrt{n^2+n\sqrt{n}}-n)}=\frac{n^{-2/3}(\sqrt{n^2+n\sqrt{n}}+n)}{n\sqrt{n}}\leq C\frac{n^{-2/3}(n+n)}{n\sqrt{n}}\leq C'n^{-7/6}.$$
You can thus use comparison test.

Comment: What do these C and C' mean? I have never come across such a notation.

Comment: It's a shortcut to say that there exists a constant $C>0$ such that... here it appears since $\sqrt{n^2+n\sqrt{n}}\leq \sqrt{2}n$. Also, $C'$ is just $2C$ here.